# Value error when i multiply 2 cells - vba

Tags: vba, valueerror

I encountered a value error when i was going through the last case (1 price and 1 qty)

sample data:

qty is 100.345/300.456 or 300.345 or 300.345/500.369/500.456

price is 300/400/500 or 300 or 300/400

data for qty and price will always be the same number so if there are 2 qty, there will be 2 prices, 3 qty will pair with 3 different prices

therefore, there are only 3 possible cases, 1 qty & 1 price, 2 qty & 2 price, 3 qty & 3 price

my expected output would be the summation of qty*price converted to $#,##0.00

```
Function qty_price(qty As string, price As string)

    Dim price_1 As Double
    Dim price_2 As Double
    Dim price_3 As Double

    Dim slash_pos As Integer
    Dim slash_pos2 As Integer

    Dim qty_1 As Double
    Dim qty_2 As Double
    Dim qty_3 As Double

    price_1 = Val(Left(price, 3))
    price_2 = Val(Mid(price, 5, 3))
    price_3 = Val(Right(price, 3))

    slash_pos = InStr(1, qty, "/")
    qty_1 = Val(Left(qty, slash_pos - 1))
    slash_pos2 = InStr(9, qty, "/")
    qty_3 = Val(Right(qty, Len(qty) - slash_pos2))


    If InStr(1, qty, "/") <> 0 Then
        ' 3 price and 3 qty
        If Len(price) = 11 Then
            qty_2 = Mid(qty, slash_pos + 1, slash_pos2 - slash_pos - 1)
            qty_price = qty_1 * price_1 + qty_3 * price_3 + Val(qty_2) * price_2
        ' 2 price and 2 quantity
        ElseIf Len(price) = 7 And Len(qty) < 16 Then
            qty_2 = Right(qty, Len(qty) - slash_pos)
            qty_price = qty_1 * price_1 + Val(qty_2) * price_3

        End If

    Else
        ' 1 price and 1 qty
        If Len(price) = 3 And Len(qty) < 8 And InStr(1, qty, "/") = 0 Then
            'value error over here
            **qty_price = Val(qty) * Val(price)**

        End If
    End If

    qty_price = Format(qty_price, "$#,##0.00")

End Function
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected output and declare all your variables. And be really clear on what data types you are expecting. You are not handling the cases of where "/" is not found. Start with sorting all those things out and putting option explicit at the top of your module.

Comment: Why do you dim your qty and price as variant? why not as string? And why don't you initialize any variable at all besides those two?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment and i tried editing based on it but somehow i still encounter the value error

Comment: As mentioned by QHarr, `Option Explicit` must be at the top of the module (first line of the file), not inside the function.

Comment: Are you passing as strings e.g. "100.345 / 300.456" ? Otherwise the "/" will not be preserved and a double will be generated due to arithmetic division.

Comment: yes, both qty and price are strings as i need to preserve the "/" but there is no "/" when there is 1 qty and 1 price only

Comment: my data will always be equal on both sides so when i have 2 qty, there will only be 2 price thus i use len(price) to sift out either 2 or 3 qty

Comment: have you looked what expression val(qty) returns? if this expression is (for whatever reason) not a numeric (null / empty), couldn't then a error occur? simply add "Debug.Print Val(qty)" or "MsgBox Val(qty)" in the line before "qty_price = ...."

Comment: Which case now fails please? What values can I put in which will reproduce the error?

Comment: sorry about that if i didn't specify, the only case that fails now is when i put in 1 qty and 1 price

Comment: In that instance you are getting a value for  price_3 = Val(Right$(price, 3))  which you don't want and also this qty_1 = Val(Left$(qty, slash_pos - 1)) will fail as slash_pos will be zero and you can't do a left -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be improved but is a starter.

In the case of 1 price and 1 qty you have at least two problems to handle:

1) You are getting a value for `price_3 = Val(Right$(price, 3))` which you don't want;

2) `qty_1 = Val(Left$(qty, slash_pos - 1))` will fail as `slash_pos` will be zero and you can't do a `Left(x, -1)`.

Below I test for the case of 1 price and 1 qty and if that is the case then do the multiplication, format string and exit function. Otherwise, go on to set the value of `price_3` (though I think you need to still double check this is correct for the case of two qty and price as the program continues.)

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Debug.Print qty_price("300.345", "300")
    Debug.Print qty_price("100.345/300.456", "300/400")
    Debug.Print qty_price("300.345/500.369/500.456", "300/400/500")
End Sub

Public Function qty_price(ByVal qty As String, ByVal price As String) As String
    Dim price_1 As Double, price_2 As Double, price_3 As Double
    Dim slash_pos As Long, slash_pos2 As Long
    Dim qty_1 As Double, qty_2 As Double, qty_3 As Double

    price_1 = Val(Left$(price, 3))
    price_2 = Val(Mid$(price, 5, 3))
    slash_pos = InStr(1, qty, "/")
    slash_pos2 = InStr(9, qty, "/")

    If slash_pos = 0 And slash_pos2 = 0 Then
        qty_price = Val(qty) * Val(price)
        qty_price = Format$(qty_price, "$#,##0.00")
        Exit Function
    End If

    price_3 = Val(Right$(price, 3))
    qty_1 = Val(Left$(qty, slash_pos - 1))
    qty_3 = Val(Right$(qty, Len(qty) - slash_pos2))

    If InStr(1, qty, "/") > 0 Then
        If Len(price) = 11 Then
            qty_2 = Mid$(qty, slash_pos + 1, slash_pos2 - slash_pos - 1)
            qty_price = qty_1 * price_1 + qty_3 * price_3 + Val(qty_2) * price_2
        ElseIf Len(price) = 7 And Len(qty) < 16 Then
            qty_2 = Right$(qty, Len(qty) - slash_pos)
            qty_price = qty_1 * price_1 + Val(qty_2) * price_3
        End If
    Else
        If Len(price) = 3 And Len(qty) < 8 And InStr(1, qty, "/") = 0 Then
            qty_price = Val(qty) * Val(price)
        End If
    End If
    qty_price = Format$(qty_price, "$#,##0.00")
End Function
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation! this works perfectly fine and the other cases are not affected